# Exclude a single page from wp_list_pages()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp_list_pages() to list all of the children of a parent page in my navigation. I want to exclude 1 child page from that navigation, how would I write that?

```
<?php
 $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=20&echo=0&depth=1");
  if ($children) {?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php 
    echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
     <?php echo $children; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Wordpress Doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/)

```
wp_list_pages( array|string $args = '' )
```

> **'exclude'** (string) Comma-separated list of page IDs to exclude

You can try :

```
<?php wp_list_pages(array('exclude'=>'id')); ?> // id of page you want to exclude separated by comma
```